# Regular expression for folders

Tags: php, regex

I want a regular expression to test a string that meets the following requirements:

- It may contain `a-z` `A-Z` and `0-9`
- It may contain `-` and `_` but may not start nor end with these characters
- It may also contain a space but may not start nor end with it

It should match the following strings:

- folder_with some-content
- folderwithcontent
- folder_with_content
- folder-with content

Could someone please help me with it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your pieces, so put them together:

```
/^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9_ -]*[a-z0-9])?$/i
```

This does exactly what you're looking for. The only complicated part is allowing a single character.

Comment: You are right, you solution is even better, the explain is here: http://www.regexper.com/ just paste there.